# conda create env not working: binstar

Tags: bash, ubuntu-14.04, conda, miniconda

Installed Miniconda on Ubuntu 14.04 64bit with the bash command. Tried creating conda environment afterwards, but it always shows this error. How to fix this error? Or is there any workaround?

```
$conda create -n testenv python
Fetching package metadata: ....
Error: No packages found in current linux-64 channels matching: default_conda_env

You can search for this package on Bconda instar with

    binstar search -t conda default_conda_env

You may need to install the Binstar command line client with

    conda install binstar
```

Comment: Add: Uninstalled Miniconda and installed Anaconda. Then tried again. Still the same error: Fetching package metadata: ....
Error: No packages found in current linux-64 channels matching: default_conda_env

You can search for this package on Binstar with

    binstar search -t conda default_conda_env

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have an invalid `.condarc` file. Take a look at your `~/.condarc`. It looks like you have `default_conda_env` in your `create_default_packages` list.

Comment: Thanks, you're right! Now what should be there in `~/.condarc` file?

Comment: `create_default_packages` should be a list of packages that you want to be installed by default every time you run `conda create`. If you have a list of such packages, add them there. Otherwise, just delete that key. See http://conda.pydata.org/docs/config.html.